# Ask the user questions, then user it in a discord.js embed

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to make it so a moderator does !Host then the bot does 
What time do you want it to start?
User Response 17:00 CET
Bot then does What Gamemode
User Response Normal 2v2 or something like that
Bot Response Who do you want to host
User Response @NaP 
Bot Response Bot then replaces the values below

```
if (m == '.nap tournament' || m == '.tournament info' || m == '.nap t' || m == '.nap tourny' || m == '.ti') {
  message.channel.send({
    embed: {
      color: 000000,
      author: {
        name: bot.user.username,
        icon_url: bot.user.avatarURL
      },
      title: "**Nap Weekly Tournament**",
      description: "Every Week We Have A Tournament For All The Nappies!!!",
      fields: [{
          name: "**Time**",
          value: "Saterdays at 17:00 CET or 5:00 pm CET."
        },
        {
          name: "**Gamemode**",
          value: "Normal 2v2"
        },
        {
          name: "**Tournament Host**",
          value: "<@!" + 'Whoister#7002' +
            ">"
        }
      ],
      timestamp: new Date(),
      footer: {
        icon_url: bot.user.avatarURL,
        text: "Arrara bot"
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: I need it to ask the question then the user answers it saves everything until the user/mod does !HostDone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using the RichEmbed class built into discord.js as it looks cleaner and it's quite easy to use as well, here's an example:

```
const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setTitle("This is your title, it can hold 256 characters")
     .setAuthor("Author Name", "https://i.imgur.com/lm8s41J.png")
     .setColor(0x00AE86)
     .setDescription("Embed description here")
 message.channel.send({embed});
```

Here is the link to see the other things you can add to the embed: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RichEmbed
Then for dealing with a user response like you want to, I'd use a message collector, https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=createMessageCollector
You can find an example there as well, you can set the filter to a user ID, for example `const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id`. You can also use maxMatches to set the maximum number of messages are collected before the `end` event is emitted. `channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { maxMatches: 2 }); //Will collect 2 messages and then emit 'end' event`. The other event that is emitted is `collect` which is emitted everytime a response comes back matching your filter, and to get the content of that response you could use something such as `collector.on('collect', m => console.log("Collected:" + m.content));`. You can create multiple collectors and send a message in between to prompt the user first and then get their input.

Comment: Your first link is now broken because it appears they changed the name of the class to MessageEmbed.  Here's a working link:https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed